# Android SQLite closing database between 2 activities

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I know there are similar forum threads to this one, but I've read them and tried the methods for solving the problem but it doesn't seem to do it.
I get the:

**close() was never explicity called on database /data/data...**

**application did not close the database or cursor that was opened...**

My error does not occur directly, it happens after awhile, when I've gone back and forth between the two activities.

I use two activities which both need a connection to the database. My idea was for the first activity to close the database before the other activity starts. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    movies = new MoviesData(this);
    cursor = getTitles();
    showTitles(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    movies.close();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    movies = new MoviesData(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

This is my first activity, the second one is pretty much alike and is started upon a buttonpress. The MoviesData class is just an empty SQLiteOpenHelper class found below.

```
public class MoviesData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movies.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MoviesData(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

**I now know when the error is displayed. If I quit the application and then open it again and try to do something the error is showing. I've tried to close the database in "onDestroy()" but that doesn't help either...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work now!
I just added this to my SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
public class MoviesData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movies.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static MoviesData movies;

    private MoviesData(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static MoviesData getInstance(Context context) {
        if (movies == null) {
            movies = new MoviesData(context);
        }
        return movies;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
//
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   movies.close();
cursor.close();

}
// no need to write this code 
@Override
public void onResume() {
    movies = new MoviesData(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: If I don't have the onResume(), when I push back from the second activity to return to the first one, I don't have anything showing anymore. I need to get the information by using cursor = getTitles()

Comment: then you should use static data